# Using ChildIndex, how to stop it's behavior like pile of paper ?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In AS3, changing the childIndex of one movieclip ( say from a list of 10 movieclips), may change the childIndex of some another movieclip ( Flash probably does it to prevent outOfIndex error ) It sometimes become a headache to manage and code them, as movieclips show above each other in an unexpected manner.

Is their any inbuilt way to make movieclip stick with a particular childIndex ? ( In AS2 there were depths that kept constant from 0-9999. And it was a real breeze as compared to AS3.0)

Thanks 
Vishwas

Comment: I'd say the other way around would be a lot more complex to manage. Don't you think?

Comment: Well, the only problem i used to face in AS2.0, was sometimes by mistake, setting the same depth to more than 1 movieclip. This made the previous ones to disappear. Otherwise, i think, i was comfortable with it, as once i provided the depth, it won't change without my command.

Comment: In as3, that's the concept of the DisplayList.. It's best to deal with it in a proper way, rather than what you are trying to ask here.. IMHO that is..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to stick movieclips to a certain index in AS3.

With the display list in AS3 Adobe totally changed the concept of displaying objects. Imho,  you should not try to transfer the old display model to the new one. This will only make it harder for you. Try to cope with the new display list and start thinking the new way. You will see the display list is not as hard to use as it seems and has indeed advanteges over the old model.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a very expected manner the way Flash displays movieclips. If you have a complicated code that involves lots of adding/removing/swapping childIndexes, maybe there's another way to manage all that stuff. My personal favourite way to manage display objects is through containers (parent movieclips) that contain a group of related objects. For example, all menu items could be added to navigation_bar movieclip. Once you've created all the needed containers and added them in the display list, managing their children gets much easier later on.

Comment: when you know about the grouping, it's ok. But it becomes much more complex, when grouping may keep on changing. This would further add up the complexity of addChild and removeChild ( may cause more trouble, because they are not noticeable visually, when transferring from one parent to another )

Comment: It's still difficult to understand the problems you're experiencing. I've worked with quite complex display object lists in the past and I always found ways to manage it. If you would provide at least a hint of what are you doing, maybe it would be easier for us to propose a working solution.

Comment: I have a small 3d-town-model ( not using any 3d-engine,but just a bit of math), with a camera and 1000 movieclips at certain z-distance. When i move one of the movieclips towords camera, it should refresh it's z-index ( childIndex) , to display over the movieclips ( with larger distance from camera).
I had to go through a longer algorithm in AS3, as compared to AS2. Furthermore, i believe that the algorithm is not optimized because it loops through the childIndex of every movieclip, sorts it and then ultimately give the output. And all this happens on MouseMove !